# Sine wave clicking with Beep.BeepBeep

Tags: c#, console-application, trigonometry

Originally, my project to make a song in the windows console using C# used `Console.Beep(freq,time);`, but the unreliability of it caused desyncs.

I changed to using the [Beep Beep](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18fe83f0-5658-4bcf-bafc-2e02e187eb80/beep-beep?forum=csharpgeneral) class. The problem is that when playing a baseline, there was an audible click at the end of every note. Here's an [example](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0W6QWOcCwtE). With a single note it's not bad, but with many consecutive notes it's unbearable.

Even when I opened it in a wave editor, no matter where I cropped it it always clicked.

How can I get rid of this clicking, without installing any bulky libraries into my C# Console Project?

Comment: Good story. What is your question though? ;)

Comment: Edited for clarity @TotumusMaximus

Comment: Using that class, can you add a fade-out - amplitude goes to zero, gradually, over the last 50 milliseconds?  Say take 20% off the amplitude every ten milliseconds for the last 50?

Comment: Or, modify the class so that instead of playing the sound, at the full amplitude, for all of the samples, it ramps up during the first 100 samples and then ramps down for the last 100.  I am no expert on this, just taking wild shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ramping the amplitude up at the start of the sound and then down again at the end.  So, modify the inner loop of that beep beep class, that reads...

```
    for (int T = 0; T < Samples; T++)
    {
      short Sample = System.Convert.ToInt16(A * Math.Sin(DeltaFT * T));
      BW.Write(Sample);
      BW.Write(Sample);
    }
```

could be modified to this

```
 for (int T=0; T < Samples; T++)
 {
     double AmpRamp = 1.0D;
     if (T<1000) {
         AmpRamp = ((double) T) / 1000.0D;
     } else if (T > Samples - 1000) {
         AmpRamp = ((double) (Samples - T)) / 1000.0D;
     }
     short Sample = System.Convert.ToInt16(A*AmpRamp*Math.Sin(DeltaFT * T));
     BW.Write(Sample);
     BW.Write(Sample);
 }
```

This ramps up the amplitude for the first 1000 samples, and then ramps it down for the last 1000, but you may have to change that number of samples for the ramp.

Comment: This is not only solving the issue but also a first step towards applying an [ADSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Attack_Decay_Sustain_Release_.28ADSR.29_envelope) envelope curve, which will make the sounds a lot more interesting..

Comment: Which is funny, because I know little to nothing about acoustics, and I was just taking a shot in the dark.  The link on ADSR envelope, that you gave in your comment, was very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit difficult to explain why without delving into digital signal processing theory, but basically the click is caused because your signal has very abrupt starts and stops which translate into high frequency components that are audible as a 'click'.

If you fade-in and fade-out the first and last 10% of your signal (using e.g. Audacity) you'll find the click goes away.

Comment: Alternatively he could just ensure to only cut on a [zero-crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_crossing) in the waveform (to avoid the fading, if that is not desired)

Comment: That would be possible if I wasn't making a C# console application.

Comment: What has this to do with it?? Both way are only about the data amplitudes.

Comment: @TaW although he suggested a method that might work, he didn't answer my question. Perhaps if he provided a link to at least a wikipedia page it would be a better answer. As is, it just sounds like he didn't read my question thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I'll leave the answer, as the basic ideas still hold but agree with the solutions that apply a fade-out. Besides solving the click-issue this also is a first step towards applying an [ADSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Attack_Decay_Sustain_Release_.28ADSR.29_envelope) envelope curve, which will make the pure sine waves sounds a lot more interesting even without adding overtones..

---

The problem is with the Beep class. It doesn't take care to end on a zero-crossing, i.e. on a complete sine wave.

The most natural way to correct this is to control the number of samples it creates.

Not sure of this calculation:

```
double xx = 2 * Math.PI / Frequency;
Samples = (int)( (int)(Samples * xx) / xx);
```

Or you can truncate the data after they have been created.

You can try this rather crude way:

```
..
MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

byte[] bytes = MS.ToArray();
Array.Reverse(bytes);
int z = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i+=4)
{
    int v = bytes[i] +  bytes[i+1] +  bytes[i+2] +  bytes[i+3];
    if (v == 0) { z = i; break; }
}
MS.SetLength(bytes.Length - z);
..
```

This finds the last zero-crossing in the stream, ie the last consecutive 4 zeroes that start (or rather ends) on a multiple of 4.

I'm sure other ways to correct this will be less hackish, but it should work for starters..